# Convert nested for loop into java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to convert the below code into Java 8 `Stream` for nested for loop.

I have tried to take stream for outer loop but not sure how to write condition and assign a variable there.

```
final Map<String, String> events = new HashMap<>();
for (final Event s : result.getEvents()) {
    String eventDetail = "";
    for (final Data d : s.getData()) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(d.getValue()) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(eventDetail)) {
            eventDetail = eventDetail + "-" + d.getValue();
        } else {
            eventDetail = eventDetail + d.getValue();
        }
    }
    events.put(s.getReferenceID(), eventDetail);
}
```

Result should be map value.

Comment: Please post the `Event` and `Data` types as well. Please check this out on how to post a minimal reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Moreover your `eventDetail` is always empty here despite the event object being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your goal is to concatenate the value members of the `Data` instances of each
`Event` into a "-" separated `String`, and map this `String` to the `Event`'s reference ID.

This can be done with `Collectors.joining()`:

```
Map<String, String>
    events = result.getEvents()
                   .stream()
                   .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s.getReferenceID(),s.getData().stream().map(Data::getValue).collect(Collectors.joining("-"))))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

or, if you wish to eliminate empty values:

```
Map<String, String>
    events = result.getEvents()
                   .stream()
                   .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s.getReferenceID(),s.getData().stream().map(Data::getValue).filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty).collect(Collectors.joining("-"))))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```java
Function<Event, String> mapper = event -> event.getData().stream()
        .map(Data::getValue)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .reduce("", (value1, value2) -> value1 + "-" + value2);

final Map<String, String> events = result.getEvents().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Event::getReferenceID, mapper));
```